# Spring Boot Separate modules for api, interface and implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, multi-module, spring-bean

I am trying to build one project which has three sub-modules for api(web), interface and implementation.

Directory tree structure is like

```
spring-multi-module
--spring-api
--spring-service-server
--spring-service-stub
```

- An idea is module `spring-api` would just contain the code related to controllers and web, and `pom.xml` have spring web and `spring-service-stub` dependencies.
- The Module `spring-service-server` will contain the code related to database configuration and all service implementations, and `pom.xml` will contains the database and `spring-service-stub` dependencies.
- and the module `spring-service-stub` will contains only interfaces
  and VOs which are used by the `spring-api` and `spring-service-server`.

`pom.xml` file of the `spring-multi-module`

```
<modules>
        <module>spring-api</module>
        <module>spring-service-server</module>
        <module>spring-service-stub</module>
    </modules>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

`pom.xml` of `spring-api`

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>spring-api</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-service-stub</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

`UserSerivce.java` is the interface in `spring-service-stub` module and its implementation is on the `spring-service-server` module. `UserController.java` have the autowired `UserService` object.

And the problem is when I am trying to run the SpringBootApplication class from the `spring-api` then gets the below error on log

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userService in com.example.demo.api.controller.UserController required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.service.UserService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.example.demo.service.UserService' in your configuration.
```

Full code also added on github, you can find from https://github.com/vinitsolanki/spring-multi-module

Simply if I add use `@Import({SpringAppStub.class, SpringAppServer.class})` instead of `@Import(SpringAppStub.class)` in `SpringAppApiConfig` then also its works, It means I am spreading all entities and repository to the `spring-api` module which I don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Spring scans all classes in the sub package of @SpringBootApplication class. Since the UserController, UserService etc. classes are not in the sub-packages you need to add

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringAppApi {
```

Comment: SpringAppApi is under the `com.example.demo.api` and UserController is under the `com.example.demo.api.controller`, so for UserController we dont required to add scan, and module `spring-service-stub` & `spring-service-server` both have to its own configuration class and its have the `@ComponentScan`, That configuration class is already added under the `SpringAppApiConfig`  e.g `@Import(SpringAppStub.class) `, So don't requied to add componentscan under the `SpringAppApi`

Comment: Also I have tried to add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})` under the `SpringAppApi` which you mentioned but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

In your project you have 3 modules

```
spring-api 
spring-service-server
spring-service-stub
```

**spring-service-server** is dependent on **spring-service-stub**

**spring-api** is dependent on **spring-service-stub**

If you see this setup there is no involvement of `spring-service-server`

Ideally, it should be like this

**spring-api** should be dependent on **spring-service-server**

You can change your spring-api => `pom.xml`

remove `stub` dependency and add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-service-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

And all should work just fine.

Comment: Yes but If I do it then I am spreading all entities and repository to the spring-api module which I don't want. My all controllers will never use the Entities and repositories directly, I want to restrict the usage these from the controller, that's why I have created three modules.